# Recursively built a list of objects

Tags: c#, recursion, mono

I'm developing a game where I have a gameboard with 8x8 fields which contain a value from 1 to 9 each.

I've got a function which starts at a specific x,y-field and checks the fields next to it whether they contain a matching value. If a matching field is found it is supposed to call the function again checking the fields next to it again. At the end I want a list of all values (which are objects) which were found recursively.

```
public void CheckForMatches(int x, int y, int value){
  if (field[x,y-1].value == value){
    //add to list
    CheckForMatches[x,y-1,value]
  }
  if (field[x,y+1].value == value){
    //add to list
    CheckForMatches[x,y+1,value]
  }
  if (field[x-1,y].value == value){
    //add to list
    CheckForMatches[x-1,y,value]
  }
  if (field[x+1,y].value == value){
    //add to list
    CheckForMatches[x+1,y,value]
  }
  return null;
}
```

How do I get a list at the end of the execution containg all objects matched?

*NOTE:* I know that I need to prevent checking fields where I started but left it out here for the sake of easiness.

Comment: `return null` doesn't make sense given `public void`, and your recursive calls use the wrong brackets for parameter lists: how close is this to your actual code?

Comment: I haven't written it yet but wanted to post the question before going to bed so I can work on it in the morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the list to `CheckForMatches`. Have it simply add the match to the list when it finds one, and pass the same list to the recursive call.

Pass an empty list when you make the initial call to start the recursive search.

Comment: This seems to be the most obvious solution. After all there are already comments in the code that say `//add to list` where a simple `list.add(value);` would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a list...

```
public void CheckForMatches(int x, int y, int value, List<something> list){
  if (field[x,y-1].value == value){
    list.Add(match info)
    CheckForMatches(x,y-1,value, list)
  }
  if (field[x,y+1].value == value){
    list.Add(match info)
    CheckForMatches(x,y+1,value, list)
  }
  if (field[x-1,y].value == value){
    list.Add(match info)
    CheckForMatches(x-1,y,value, list)
  }
  if (field[x+1,y].value == value){
    list.Add(match info)
    CheckForMatches(x+1,y,value, list)
  }
}
```

Which is called the first time with something like:

```
List<something> matches = new List<something>();
CheckForMatches(0, 0, 0, matches);
```

Edit:

You need to be very careful of edge cases (like the above), since checking for a match the first if statement (field[x, y-1]) will result in an IndexOutOfBounds exception being thrown. Likewise with the other side where you are off the upper end of the array.

Comment: So C# uses call by reference for lists?

Comment: The ref is not required because you are not changing the reference of the list (creating a new list). You can modify/add/remove from the list without the ref keyword because you are modifying an existing object.

Comment: No, it uses call by value - but you are passing a reference to a list, not a list.

Comment: Read [this excellent article](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html) by Jon Skeet for more info.